# Language encoding problem with DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport reference

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, activereports

I have an encoding problem with DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport reference.
It exports my report successfully but without using encoding. So, every char in other language than English is omitted.

How can I set it? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 9):

This generally will happen because the font for the textbox in the report does not have the glyph for the characters that are missing. Since the ActiveReports PDF Export embeds the font (i.e. technically it embeds the "glyphs" from the font due to the way PDF works) those missing non-English characters that the font does not have glyphs for, appear as missing or are improperly displayed.

So you will need to make sure that the font that you're using has glyphs for all of the characters that you are exporting.

Generally the easiest way to make sure this works (and to check if this is the problem) is to set the font of the textbox or texboxes that will contain non-English characters to the font named "Arial Unicode MS" which contains most glyphs from most languages. So please try using the "Arial Unicode MS" font and see if that will resolve the problem.

Hoppe this helps.

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```